# What is the difference between scipy.interpolate.rbf and matplotlib.pyplot.contourf?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, data-visualization

I have 3 columns of data in a csv file with which I intend to create a contour map. These three columns are not grid data.
Initially, I created grid data using the following function:

```
def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
  xi = linspace(min(x), max(x), resX)
  yi = linspace(min(y), max(y), resY)
  Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
  X, Y = meshgrid(xi, yi)
  return X, Y, Z
```

Then I imported the data, prepared it and passed it to the function.

```
X, Y, Z = grid(x, y, z)
contour = plt.contourf (X, Y, Z)
```

I got the following image [Contour 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS1T4.png) using matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.

Now I tried creating a similar contour map using a code snippet I found online using scipy.interpolate.rbf and it looks like this [Contour 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUXgV.png).

```
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)


rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

plt.imshow(zi)
```

What is the difference between the rbf function and contour function? For the same data, the rbf function is creating a fully occupied contour map whereas the contourf function is only plotting the data at (x,y) -> z.

I am looking to create a fully occupied plot like the one created by rbf but it doesn't work with large data as I get the following error

```
LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.
```